# Error: Project 'testapp' could not be found in workspace issue when trying to create the build of my universal app in angular 6

Tags: angular6

I am trying to create an universal app in angular 6 by folllowing this [link](https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/angular-6-universal-simple-guide/).After doing the steps mentioned in the link I trying to take build of my universal app,but it shows below error.

```
Project 'testapp' could not be found in workspace.
Error: Project 'testapp' could not be found in workspace.
```

can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Your project's name might actually be Testapp instead of testapp. That was the problem with mine. Hope this is not too late for you mate.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the project name is correct.
You can find your correct project name in local workspace file (*app/angular.json*)